# TypeORM EventSubscribe triggered at any event

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, subscriber

Hi have created a EventSubscriber in TypeORM to listen to a specific entity and it's events on database level (quite straightforward)

But this Subscriber is being triggered at any CRUD operation in any table, or maybe fired due to indirect relations with the targeted entity (hopefully not) without the targeted entity/table not being CRUD-ed

This is how my subscriber looks:

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class ImpactViewSubscriber
  implements EntitySubscriberInterface<TargetedEntity>
{
  logger: Logger = new Logger(ImpactViewSubscriber.name);
  listenTo(): any {
    return TargetedEntity;
  }

  afterTransactionCommit(event: TransactionCommitEvent): Promise<any> | void {
    this.logger.log(`Event subscriber fired...`);
    return event.queryRunner.query(
      `some query...`,
    );
  }
}
```

And it's (apparently) properly imported in **typeorm.config.ts**

```
 ....
 subscribers: [join(__dirname, '..', '**/*.subscriber.{ts,js}')],
```

So for some reason the logic inside **afterTransactionCommit()** is being triggered at any interaction of any table, also when I first run the app (which is annoying).
What am I doing wrong? I just want to fire the logic when any CRUD operation is donde to my target entity, ideally after a transaction, as my target entity will only receive bulk INSERTS or DELETES

Any idea of where is the error?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I also tested using `afterInsert()` and `afterRemove()`
which does not make the logic get triggered at any event of any other table, but it is being triggered for each row inserted in the target table. And since I only have bulk operations, this is not useful.

My use cases are: Bulk inserts in the table, and bulk deletes by cascade. I am making sure those happens on a single transaction. Any ideas as to what can I do using typeorm avoiding to manually create specific DB triggers or similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a quite old post.
But have you tried to remove :any from the listener call?

```
listenTo() {
   return TargetedEntity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Due to our strict TS rules, I really have to type the return type. I remember having some issue setting the target entity as the return type.
However, this should not have nothing to do with the issue as this is just TS typing and has no effect during runtime

Comment: @SeekanDestroy, have you been able to get this to behave well? I'm noticing the same issue also. However, a workaround I am thinking of now is to check if the `databaseEntity` object in the `event` object is an instance of the entity that should be listened to. So, at the first line of the event listener, I'd have a check:

`if (!(databaseEntity instanceof ActualEntity)) return;`

But I'd still like to know the fix for this.